# RunRev: Revlet (RevWeb) plugin

Tags: livecode

Can anyone provide the RunRev revlet plugin for the browsers (RevWeb) for OSX as currently the page seems to be updated until Tue. 14th May.

I would be very grateful to have it beforehand if possible, any google search always leads to the runrev-page currently in maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://midgard.on-rev.com/uploads/revWebInstallerX86.dmg

Please note that the revWeb plugin is not currently officially supported.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but somehow it's not working with neither Chrome, FF nor Safari 32bit. No revlet is being loaded.

Comment: Try Camino, that is the only browser I know for sure that it reliably works with.